# Masking Authorization field using logback.xml regex

Tags: java, regex, logging, logback, spring-logback

I am trying to mask Authorization field in logback.xml.
The possible values are

1. Authorization:"Bearer abcdfdd..................................."
2. Authorization:"Basic abcdfdd==="                     (ends with ==)
3. Authorization: Bearer abcdfdd...................................

In logback.xml

```
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

  <springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>
 
  <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{64} - %replace(%replace(%replace(%msg){'Authorization:&quot;Bearer\\s?[\\w\\-\\. ]*', 'Authorization:xxxxx'}){'Authorization:&quot;Basic\\s?[\\w\\-\\. ]*', 'Authorization:xxxxx'}){'Authorization:\\s?[\\w\\-\\. ]*', 'Authorization:xxxxx'}%n"/>
  
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
      <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

the output is

1. Authorization:xxxx
2. Authorization:xxxxx==
3. Authorization:xxxx

I am not sure what's the problem with my regex, the regex doesn't replace second point ==.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this simple regex expression for your given possible values

```
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{64} - **%replace(%msg){'Authorization: Bearer s*(.*)', 'Authorization:****'}**%n"/>
```